# Does this limit proof about $\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{100}{x} = 100$ makes any sense?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I deduced this proof from the proof of the limit of a reciprocal property (Michael Spivak Calculus 3rd edition, pages 103-104). The exercise goes as follows:

**Exercise**. Using epsilon-delta definition, show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1} \left[f(x) = \dfrac{100}{x}\right] = 100$.

**Lemma**. If $y_0 \not = 0$ and $$|y-y_0| < \min\left(\dfrac{|y_0|}{2}, \dfrac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2}\right)$$ then $y \not = 0$ and $$\left| \dfrac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|< \epsilon$$.

This lemma is true and its proof can be found in the aforementioned text, pages 102-103.

**Proof**

Let $g(x) = \dfrac{x}{100}$. Then

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1} g(x)&= \lim_{x \to 1}x \cdot \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{1}{100} && \text{this by product property of limits}\\
&= \frac{1}{100}
\end{align}
$$$$

From this we have that for all $\epsilon_{1}>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that, for all $x$ if $$0 < |x-1| < \delta_1$$ then $$\left|\dfrac{x}{100} - \dfrac{1}{100}\right|< \epsilon_1$$ Because $$\min\left(\dfrac{\left|\frac{1}{100}\right|}{2}, \dfrac{\epsilon\left(\left|\frac{1}{100}\right|\right)^2}{2}\right) > 0$$ then if $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x$ if $$0 < |x-1| < \delta $$ then $$\left|g(x) - \dfrac{1}{100}\right| = \left|\dfrac{x}{100} - \dfrac{1}{100}\right|< \min\left(\dfrac{\left|\frac{1}{100}\right|}{2}, \dfrac{\epsilon\left(\left|\frac{1}{100}\right|\right)^2}{2}\right) $$ By lemma, we therefore have that $g(x) \not = 0$ and $$\left|\dfrac{1}{g(x)} - \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{100}}\right| = \left|\dfrac{100}{x} - 100\right| < \epsilon$$.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It probably does. But why does it need a proof? The function is obviously continuous at $x=1\,.$

Comment: "Finding $\delta$ such that for all $\epsilon...$" is the wrong order. $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon,$ so one $\delta$ will not work for all $\epsilon.$

Comment: @KurtG. You are correct, is clear that that's the limit. However, I need to solve the exercise of verifying the limit finding that delta.

Comment: Your ordering of things is strange. Why are you talking about $g(x)=x/100$ after the lemma, rather than proving the lemma? If you know the lemma is true from your text, at least tell us that. But the occurrence of "**Proof**" right after the Lemma statement indicates to most readers that you are proving the lemma.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry for missing that. The lemma is indeed true, I'll modify the question citing where the proof can be found. Regarding your first suggestion, probably I wrongly translated the exercise.

Comment: Why $0<|x-2|<\delta$ when you are sending $x\to1?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes it should be $| x-1|$ it seems I stumped my head so bad with another exercise involving that one that is now tattooed in my brain.

Comment: Use
$$
\textstyle|\frac1x-\frac1y|=\frac{|y-x|}{xy}\le\frac{\delta}{x(x-\delta)}
$$
to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ threre exists a $\delta$ s.t. for all $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ the RHS (hence the LHS) is smaller than $\epsilon\,.$ This shows the continuity of the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ on $(0,\infty)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. your observation IS a proof 